# C$^*$-algebras in which the spectral radius is comparable to the norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

For every commutative C$^*$-algebra the spectral radius is equal to the norm. My question is:

> > For which C$^*$-algebras $\mathcal A$ does there exist a constant $C>0$ such that $$C\|a\| \leq r(a), \ \ \forall a\in \mathcal A?$$

Comment: The answer (which is A must be commutative) is basically contained in this question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/125945/quasinilpotent-elements-of-group-c-star-algebras : If A is non-commutative it has a non-zero nilpotent element which has spectral radius 0

Comment: Delightful! Thank you @CalebEckhardt.